# How can I Ioad data from hadoop to datastax graph using graphLoader ? (How can I directly read files from hadoop using graphLoader)

Tags: hadoop, datastax-enterprise-graph

Do I have to copy the file from hadoop to local directoy :

hadoop fs -get [hadoop src] [local dst]

In order to use:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/dglCSV.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to copy the data to a local system. You can reference a file on HDFS directly and read it in from there.

```
    def source = File.csv(dfs_uri + "person.csv.gz").gzip().delimiter("|")
    load(source).asVertices {
        label vertexLabel
        key "id"
    }
```

This is an example of a mapping script where a compressed csv file is read from HDFS. 'dfs_uri' is a command line parameter which specifies the URI to the HDFS directory in which the file is stored.